# Limiting results by multiple attributes

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got data with record, version, title and expires fields.
Record is a non-unique field, and each record can have a number of versions.

In search results, I need to only show one of each version.

So is it possible to search by title for articles that on/before a certain date, but only return one result for each version.

For example, given this data:

```
{"record": 1, "version": 1, "title": "Hello", "expires": "2011-08-17 00:00:00"},
{"record": 1, "version": 2, "title": "Hello", "expires": "2012-08-17 00:00:00"},
{"record": 2, "version": 1, "title": "Hello world", "expires": "2010-08-17 00:00:00"},
{"record": 2, "version": 2, "title": "Hello world", "expires": "2011-08-17 00:00:00"},
{"record": 2, "version": 3, "title": "Hello world", "expires": "2012-08-17 00:00:00"},
```

searching for documents containing "Hello" in the title, that expired on/before 2012-08-18, should return:

```
{"record": 1, "version": 2, "title": "Hello", "expires": "2012-08-17 00:00:00"},
{"record": 2, "version": 3, "title": "Hello world", "expires": "2012-08-17 00:00:00"}
```

(the most recent 'version' of each record).

Any ideas?

Will I have to iterate over the results outside of ES? 
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you considered nesting the versioned data as sub-objects in your indexed document?  So there would only ever be one `record 1` in your index, but it would contain a `versions` field that maintained an ordered list with `version_num` field. I think you might be able to use some sort of scripting to retrieve only the latest item at that point... maybe?

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is directly possible. Also @James, es cannot only return 'matching' parts of a nested document, the whole doc is returned if it is a hit.

Comment: I'm sorry @JamesAddison I misread your comment (sub-objects turned into nested docs). Yes I think this would work. Otherwise, you could have a boolean "latest" flag and filter by that. The decision is whether to do the extra work at index-time or at search-time.

Comment: Thanks @JamesAddison I'll a look at using sub-documents to structure the data

Comment: Parent/child might be a viable option here as well, depending on your use case? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called field collapsing and it's one of the few features Apache Solr has and ElasticSearch doesn't.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing

There's a lot of requests for this feature in ElasticSearch but it's not implemented yet.